# How to fix typo errors easily in VSCode with many middlewares imported? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, middleware

I am learning server/client communication.
This is part of code from my server side.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ credential: true, origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN }));
```

I tried to communicate with the server with Chrome browser and my client side fetch() function threw errror.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked
by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the 
request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

No wonder, since I gave cors property as 'credential'. It is 'credentials'.
Problem is, there was no error code showing on this matter, so I thought there was problem with the response header.

**It took me almost a day to find out that one 's' missing caused this problem!!!!!**

If I knew better about what I imported(cors middleware), I could probably have better idea where to look at. But I am in the learning process. Since there was no better clue for my level of knowledge, I had to suffer many hours to finally point out this typo.

My question is, is there any tool I am missing out about this matter?
Is there any way to get better suggestion for typos or warning for potential problems, especially with so many middlewares imported?
I know there is ESLint but it didn't give me a warning about this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)? It is a type-safe version of js. It's so similar to JS that I can't tell whether it's TypeScript or pure JS just from the sample code you gave me.

If you haven't use it, it may help you solve your problem. But since you are using VSCode, I guess you should already know typescript.

Moving from JS to TypeScript is easy, and you can mix the two in one project. In one of my older projects, I gradually changed the code to TypeScript one by one.

Comment: No I only heard about TypeScript. I don't know what it is. Thank you for guidance. I will definitely check it out!